# Volatile/modified return address

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, volatile, jit

Consider a C function (with external linkage) like the following one:

```
void f(void **p)
{
  /* do something with *p */
}
```

Now assume that `f` is being called in a way such that `p` points to the return address of `f` on the stack, as in the following code (assuming the System V AMD64 ABI):

```
leaq -8(%rsp), %rdi
callq f
```

What may happen is that the code of `f` modifies the return address on the stack by assigning a value to *p. Thus the compiler will have to treat the return address on the stack as a volatile value. How can I tell the compiler, gcc in my case, that the return address is volatile?

Otherwise, the compiler could, at least in principle, generate the following code for `f`:

```
pushq %rbp
movq 8(%rsp), %r10
pushq %r10
## do something with (%rdi)
popq %r10
popq %rbp
addq 8,%rsp
jmpq *%r10
```

Admittedly, it is unlikely that a compiler would ever generate code like this but it does not seem to be forbidden without any further function attributes. And this code wouldn't notice if the return address on the stack is being modified in the middle of the function because the original return address is already retrieved at the beginning of the function.

P.S.: As has been suggested by Peter Cordes, I should better explain the purpose of my question: It is about garbage collecting dynamically generated machine code using a moving garbage collector: The function `f` stands for the garbage collector. The callee of `f` may be a function whose code is being moved around while `f` is running, so I came up with the idea of letting `f` know the return address so that `f` may modify it accordingly to whether the memory area the return address points to has been moved around or not.

Comment: All of this is undefined behaviour

Comment: In C99, certainly. But this does not mean that it won't  have definite behaviour in a real-world implementation like gcc using the right function attributes/pragmas. And this is what my question is about.

Comment: Come back when you have a real problem in real code that really compiles.  A theoretical discussion of implementation-dependent stuff is tedious.

Comment: This is from a real problem in real code.

Comment: @Marc: You need to wrap the function, with a minimal assembly function, that calls `f()` and uses the return address on the stack. If the purpose of `f()` is just to change the return address, you should write it entirely in assembly.

Comment: The thing with platform-specific code is that you can never rely on it working after an upgrade of the compiler - you need to create tests that you run after every upgrade so that you are notified when it breaks.

Comment: Are you trying to implement `longjmp`?  Why do you want this, and why aren't you just writing it in assembly in the first place?

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks for the positive comment. The real purpose of `f` is doing a garbage collection (which may move the code calling `f` around so that the return address may have to be adjusted by `f` before returning to the callee). As writing a GC in assembly is not what I would like to do, I am going to evaluate your second suggestion using a wrapper function.

Comment: @PeterCordes If I knew a stable machine language interface to setjmp, I could use this to jump out of `f` using the modified return address.

Comment: You should put that explanation of writing a GC for JITed code into the question.  It makes a LOT more sense with that as a motivation!

Comment: If the optimizer can't see the code that called it, you don't need to worry about it returning without having actually stored through the pointer.  It can't just leave the value in a register, or in some other memory location.  Since `f`'s caller must be written in asm to pass a pointer to the return address, even link-time optimization won't be able to find it and break it.  But I'd still vote for @Nominal's suggestion to do the return-address munging in asm directly, instead of through a C pointer arg.

Comment: @Marc: Yes, a wrapper makes more and more sense. You can have the wrapper function (which is of course in the part of the code that does not move around, not being JITed) supply an extra pointer, pointing to the return address in the wrapper function stack frame. The SYSV AMD64 ABI is simple enough that if you have say 5 parameters for `f()`, you can set the sixth (`%r9`) to point to the return address on stack; as a pure assembly function you'd then not need even a proper stack frame, and the wrapper would be minimal. Runtime cost would be just the extra call.

Comment: The runtime cost of one extra call would be neglectable as `f` is going to do a GC when being called. :-)

Comment: To whoever voted down: Could you explain why and say how you would improve the question?

Comment: Forgot to mention: if you modify the return value in asm directly, you should still write a value to the stack and RET, rather than just popping it off and using JMP to the new return address.  The former will cause one branch mispredict on the RET, the latter will unbalance the return-address predictor stack and cause branch mispredictions on RETs all the way up the call chain.

Comment: re: downvote / lack of upvotes: Don't just add a P.S. at the end.  Having your use-case in mind while reading the whole question makes it much more understandable.  I totally agree with John Zwinck's comments from before you clarified that this looks like just a silly theoretical "what if I try to break the compiler this way" question.  You can and should re-word a lot of the early part to focus more on the ultimate goal rather than on your attempt at an implementation.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I have already taken care of this using the solution with the wrapper function. The wrapper function is not called but jumped into, and the return address (which may have to be adjusted) is delivered through a register. At the end of the wrapper function, an absolute jump is made.
(That said, the return-address predictor stack is not too relevant for my use case because I am using explicit continuations in my jitted code and not the SysV ABI with call/ret pairs.)

Comment: @Marc: In that case, pass the final jump target address to the wrapper function in some register. Wrapper sets up a proper stack frame (16 byte alignment on x86-64 and so on), calls the GC using e.g. `void *gc(void *addr)`, using the standard ABI on each architecture (there are only a few ABIs, and you can [detect/check for](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) them at compile time), and after the return, wrapper reverts the stack frame, then jumps to the returned address. Very simple and straightforward, and no shenanigans of any sort needed: *wrapper bridges JIT to standard ABI*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the SysV ABI (Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, Mac OS X / macOS) on AMD64/x86-64, you only need a trivial assembly function wrapped around the actual garbage collector function.

The following `f.s` defines `void f(void *)`, and calls the real GC, `real_f(void *, void **)`, with the added second parameter pointing to the return address.

```
    .file       "f.s"
    .text

    .p2align    4,,15
    .globl      f
    .type       f, @function

f:
    movq        %rsp, %rsi
    call        real_f
    ret

    .size       f, .-f
```

If `real_f()` already has two other parameters, use `%rdx` (for the third) instead of `%rsi`. If three to five, use `%rcx`, `%r8`, or `%r9`, respectively. SysV ABI on AMD64/x86-64 only supports up to six non-floating-point parameters in registers.

Let's test the above with a small `example.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern void f(void *);

void real_f(void *arg, void **retval)
{
    printf("real_f(): Returning to %p instead of %p.\n", arg, *retval);
    *retval = arg;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Function and label addresses:\n");
    printf("%p f()\n", f);
    printf("%p real_f()\n", real_f);
    printf("%p one_call:\n", &&one_call);
    printf("%p one_fail:\n", &&one_fail);
    printf("%p one_skip:\n", &&one_skip);
    printf("\n");

    printf("f(one_skip):\n");
    fflush(stdout);

one_call:
    f(&&one_skip);

one_fail:
    printf("At one_fail.\n");
    fflush(stdout);

one_skip:
    printf("At one_skip.\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that the above relies on both GCC behaviour (`&&` providing the address of a label) as well as GCC behaviour on AMD64/x86-64 architecture (object and function pointers being interchangeable), as well as the C compiler not making any of the myriad optimizations they are allowed to do to the code in `main()`.

(It does not matter if `real_f()` is optimized; it's just that I was too lazy to work out a better example in `main()`. For example, one that creates a small function in an executable data segment that calls `f()`, with `real_f()` moving that data segment, and correspondingly adjusting the return address. That would match OP's scenario, and is just about the only practical use case for this kind of manipulation I can think of. Instead, I just hacked a crude example that might or might not work for others.)

Also, we might wish to declare `f()` as having two parameters (they would be passed in `%rdi` and `%rsi`) too, with the second being irrelevant, to make sure the compiler does not expect `%rsi` to stay unchanged. (If I recall correctly, the SysV ABI lets us clobber it, but I might remember wrong.)

On this particular machine, compiling the above with

```
gcc -Wall -O0 f.s example.c -o example
```

running it

```
./example
```

produces

```
Function and label addresses:
0x400650 f()
0x400659 real_f()
0x400729 one_call:
0x400733 one_fail:
0x40074c one_skip:

f(one_skip):
real_f(): Returning to 0x40074c instead of 0x400733.
At one_skip.
```

Note that if you tell GCC to optimize the code (say, `-O2`), it will make assumptions about the code in `main()` it is perfectly allowed to do by the C standard, but which may lead to all three labels having the exact same address. This happens on my particular machine and GCC-5.4.0, and of course causes an endless loop. It does not reflect on the implementation of `f()` or `real_f()` at all, only that my example in `main()` is quite poor. I'm lazy.